# setting generated clock constraints (create_generated_clock)

Tags: clock, xilinx

Xilinx complains about a derived clock in my design:
[derived clock ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx001.png)

What do I have to do so that I can create this sampled clock pulse that I need for my statemachine and logic to work?  I'm not sure what the issue is with a signal created this way.

From what I gather, I need to create a create_generated_clock constraint, but how do I know how to constrain this signal? Is the idea to force the routing in the FPGA to maintain a "fixed" relationship (within some tolerance) between the input clock signal and the "newclk" signal? And, I could I make that be whatever I need it to be ?

Comment: What is the complain you get? Can you paste the HDL source code and give us more info on how you structured your Vivado project?

Comment: In general the clock constraints are needed so that the place and route tool will be able to calculate the max delay between flip flops, and then calculate if timing is met. Where is your clock coming from? If it is from a PLL wizard, then the clock constraints are generated from you. If it's an external pin you need a `create clock` to tell the period.